# Could not convert string to float from tkinter field

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Keeps popping up saying

```
File "script1.py", line 6, in conversion
    weight = float(e1_value.get()) * 1000
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

when I run my code, any ideas please?

Can't find any spaces or anything to tell me why it won't convert the input.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def conversion():
    weight = float(e1_value.get()) * 1000
    weight = float(e2_value.get()) * 2.20462
    weight = float(e3_value.get()) * 35.274
    t1.insert(END,weight)


e1_value = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, textvariable = e1_value)
e1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

e2_value = StringVar()
e2 = Entry(window, textvariable = e2_value)
e2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

e3_value = StringVar()
e3 = Entry(window, textvariable = e3_value)
e3.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

b1 = Button(window, text = 'Convert', command = conversion)
b1.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

t1 = Text(window, height = 1, width = 20)
t1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

window.mainloop()
```

Should hopefully output into three seperate boxes the converted weight.

Comment: Doesn't it tell you what line of code it's complaining about?

Comment: Please show the full and exact error message.

Comment: You should copy/paste your input as well. Maybe a thing with locale and comma vs. dot as decimal separator.

Comment: Added in full error mesage thanks

Comment: Your code is taking the 3 separate values from e1,e2,e3 and converting those? Though in each line of the conversion function you overwrite the weight.
So if you write values in the 3 separate boxes and click convert you will see it gives you a number in the single box.

Comment: Changed my code to take input from the first box and output into the other three boxes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not give your inputs, but your error indicates the first field is empty. Your code works fine if you fill out all 3 inputs. The problem is you

```
def conversion():
    weight = float(e1_value.get()) * 1000
    weight = float(e2_value.get()) * 2.20462
    weight = float(e3_value.get()) * 35.274
    t1.insert(END,weight)
```

so when `convert` is hit - you try to convert all three input fields to float, regardless of whether someone typed there or not. You get an error on `e1` - fill that out with a number and will get an error on `e2`, fill that and - you guessed it - you will get an error on `e3`. One possible way to handle this:

```
from tkinter import messagebox  
def conversion():
    try:
        weight = float(e1_value.get()) * 1000
        weight = float(e2_value.get()) * 2.20462
        weight = float(e3_value.get()) * 35.274
        t1.insert(END,weight)
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror("What the hell?","Please type a valid number in all three fields!")
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Oh no!","Got some other weird error:\n"+str(e))
```